# error: restarting script because .git/FETCH_HEAD changed

Tags: node.js, forever

I restart node.js server with forever by watchin files. Every few minutes I get message:
`error: restarting script because .git/FETCH_HEAD changed` which restarts my server.

How to avoid that? It shall restart upon file change not git head change.

Watching script:

```
HOME=/root forever \
    --pidFile $PIDFILE \
    -a \
    -l $LOGFILE \
    --minUptime $MIN_UPTIME \
    --spinSleepTime $SPIN_SLEEP_TIME \
    --watch \
    --watchDirectory=$APPLICATION_PATH \
    start $APPLICATION_PATH$APPLICATION_SCRIPT 2>&1 > /dev/null &
RETVAL=$?
log_end_msg $RETVAL
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

see #20 comment in:
https://github.com/foreverjs/forever/issues/235

this problem is not solved in forever, works for many, fail for others.
many developers fixed but 'cause is a pull request without tests still not merging yet.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `watchIgnore` directive to ignore your .git folder, just add this option :

```
--watchIgnore "**/.git/**"
```

Comment: I've did  `--watchIgnore .git` and still getting `error: restarting script because project/.git/FETCH_HEAD changed`

Comment: I've updated my answer, have a go with `"**/.git/**"`, as forever expects a pattern

Comment: Now it ignores everything. `--watch \ --watchIgnore "**/.git/**" \ --watchDirectory=$APPLICATION_PATH \
`

Comment: That is strange, it works for me. Have you tried using a .foreverignore file?